# When the page is opened for the first time the websocket is in the connecting state, and when the page is refreshed later, it switches to open state

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, websocket, react-context

I am trying to establish a websocket connection.

I'm writing the structure inside a useEffect in a context.

But there is one problem. When I open the page for the first time, the readyState of the websocket is not 1 in the console. 1 means open.
It comes as 0, that is, in the Connecting state. At the same time, when you write console.log to a function in socket.onclose event, it gives that console.

After the page is opened, when you refresh the page once, it makes the websocket connection.

You need to be able to control this situation. I wrote a few recursive solutions for this, but I could not find a solution.

```
export const NotificationsContext = createContext(initialState);

export const NotificationsProvider = (props) => {

useEffect(async () => {

    let url = `http://localhost:8080/notifs`.replace('http', 'ws');

    let socket = new WebSocket(url)
    console.log(socket); 
    console.log(socket.readyState); // readyState is 0. mean CONNECTING.

    socket.onclose = () => {
        console.log('closed check') // in console.
        socket = new WebSocket(url)
    }
    socket.onmessage = (data) => {
        const notifData = JSON.parse(data.data);
        console.log(notifData) // not in console.
    }
    console.log('connected');
}, []);

const [my_data, dispatch] = useReducer(userDetailsReducer, initialState);

return <NotificationsContext.Provider value={{ notifications, my_data, dispatch }}>. 
{children}</NotificationsContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: What do you need this `readyState` for?

Comment: `readyState` just tells you the current state of a WebSocket @KonradLinkowski.